# How to empty a list to clear input field after form submission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to develop a form with **React-Bootstrap** and using **Form.Control.Feedback** to show the errors.

What I want to do now is after the user submitted the form successfully, both the input fields will be cleared so that if the user wants to submit again, a page `reload/refresh` won't be needed.

However, I can't seem to make it work by using `setForm({})` as I will get the error `length.undefined` after submitting again.

[image: Edit zealous-mopsa-o39nb]

Comment: Looks like you are not using input values from your state. Meaning they are not looking like a controlled component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will need to have a few changes to your code:**

- First, Only check for errors if your form is not empty:

```
const newErrors = form && findFormErrors();  // <-- Check for form is not empty first
```

- Second, make your input a controlled component by adding values from state to it:

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter Name"
  value={form.name}  // <-- HERE
  onChange={(e) => setField("name", e.target.value)}
  isInvalid={!!errors.name}
  required
/>;
```

- Lastly, initialize your state with empty values, so the error about un-controlled component to controlled component won't appear.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({ name: "", password: "" });
```

**Working example:**

[image: Edit funny-black-irdy1]

Answer (score 1):

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newErrors = findFormErrors();
    // Conditional logic:
    if (Object.keys(newErrors).length > 0) {
      // We got errors!
      setErrors(newErrors);
    } else {
      // No errors! Put any logic here for the form submission!
      alert("Thank you for your feedback! " + form.name + " " + form.password);
      setForm({ name: "", password: "" });  **// This was added**
      console.log(form);
    }
  };

........................................
        <Col sm="6">
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={form.name} **// This was added**
            placeholder="Enter Name"
            onChange={(e) => setField("name", e.target.value)}
            isInvalid={!!errors.name}
            required
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {errors.name}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label className="fw-bold" column sm="4">
          Password
        </Form.Label>
        <Col sm="6">
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={form.password} **// This was added**
            placeholder="New Password"
            onChange={(e) => setField("password", e.target.value)}
            isInvalid={!!errors.password}
            required
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {errors.password}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>

..................................
```

There were a few changes required.

1. Setting `setForm({ name: "", password: "" });`.
2. Setting value to the input fields.